# Why can't I add another variable in the class using setter and getter?

Tags: python, oop, setter, getter

I wrote a class called person and used setter and getter. At first, the code was working fine when I used one variable.However when I added another variable , it said that  2 required  positional arguments were missing:"name" and "age".

```
 class person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age 


    def set_name(self,y):
        self.name = y

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


    def set_age(self,x):
        self.age = x

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

p1 = person()
p1.set_name("Armeen")
p1.set_age("20")
print(p1.get_age())
print(p1.get_name())
```

Comment: You are calling `person()` but `person.__init__` expects `name` and `age`

Comment: On a side note, this is not how getters and setter are supposed to be implemented in Python. Do some reading on the `property` decorator

Comment: @DeepSpace please explain , what u mean by that? What was wrong here?

Comment: It means that your class' constructor expects two values for `name` and `age` respectively and you do not provide any of them when you call `person()`. If you wish to set `age` and `name` after callling your constructor you can rewrite `__init__` as follows: `def __init__(self): self.name = '' self.age = 0`

Comment: See the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) of `property()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__` method takes two arguments namely name and age. You aren't providing any argument when creating an instance of `Person`. So you may want to do the following:

```
p1 = person('Armeen', 20)
```

As opposed to

```
p1 = person()
```

Or if you want to allow user not to specify name and age at the time of instance creation, you can set those parameter as optional by doing the following change in `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, name = None, age = None): ##This would work with your code as well
```